# Prettier format on save doesn't work anymore

Tags: node.js, reactjs, prettier

So for my last React project everything worked fine, but now that I'm setting up a nodejs and react project, it doesn't work like it used to. My folder structure is like that, and I want to have the same settings for prettier for react and nodejs. The second image is my settings.json file, so I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that javascript is blurred. Not sure what the problem is though and I hope someone is able to help me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was not working for me as well and I was puzzled as to why? 
There is a format on save option. there it is mentioned, that autoSave should not be set to after delay.
I had autoSave set to  **after delay**, so unset that setting and prettier started doing it work back, then I rolled back the autoSave to **afterDelay** and prettier still kept working, i.e. **formatting on Save!**

Comment: so it is same old joke, that sometimes program work when you restart your application